# How to store multiple custom meta box

Tags: php, custom-field, metabox, post-meta

I am trying to store a multidimensional array of a Quiz where I dynamically add question box. But I am not able to figure out how to store dynamically added question box. The code is below

```
function wporg_add_custom_box()
{
$screens = ['sr-quiz'];
foreach ($screens as $screen) {
    add_meta_box(
        'quiz_box_id',
        'Quiz Box', 
        'wporg_custom_box_html',  
        $screen                   
    );
   }
 }
 add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'wporg_add_custom_box');

 function wporg_custom_box_html($post)
 {
 jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    function addQuestion(){
        var question = jQuery('#question-template').clone();
        question.css("display","block").removeAttr('id');
        jQuery('#questions').append(question);
    }

    function renameQuestions(){
        jQuery('.question-box').each(function(i,v){
            jQuery(this).find('.question_id').html(i);
        });
    }

    jQuery('#add-question').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addQuestion();
        renameQuestions();
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click','.del-question', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).closest('.question-box').remove();
        renameQuestions();
    });
});

<div id="questions">
<div class="question-box" id="question-template" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Question <span class="question_id"></span></h2>

    <input type="text" name="quiz[english][ques_title]" class="ques_title" placeholder="Enter question title" value="">

    <textarea name="quiz[english][ques_desc]" class="ques_desc" rows="4" placeholder="Explaination here...."></textarea>

    <a class="del-question button" href="#" data-id="1">Remove</a>
</div>
<a id="add-question" class="button" href="#">Add</a>
</div>
<?php
}
function wporg_save_postdata($post_id)
{
   $arr = $_POST['quiz'];
   update_post_meta(
        $post_id,
       'quiz_data',
       $arr
   );
}
add_action('save_post', 'wporg_save_postdata');
```

I am not able to figure out the solution, I even tried **quiz[][quiz][english][ques_title]**. But this did not work

Comment: I don't see any php here.  Did you intend to do something like `<?php echo quiz['english']['ques_title'] ?>` ?

Comment: @ChrisStage, sorry for that now I have added the PHP code

Comment: I want to have different arrays like, quiz[0][quiz][english][quiz_title].....quiz[1][quiz][english][quiz_title]....so on. But I am confused on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has nothing to do with wordpress.
Shouldn't this question be on stackoverflow?

HTML:

```
name="quest_title[]"
name="quest_desc[]"
```

PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['quest_title'] as $key => $title)
{
    $desc = $_POST['quest_desc'][$key];
    //Here do whathever you want with this $title and $desc.
}
```

Solution: use empty brackets at the END of the name tag.

Comment: I have added some wordpress function which I forgot to add. Now could you help ?

Comment: You want "quiz[0][quiz][english][quiz_title]" but you have to put brackets at the end, so HTML would identify it as an array. Then, iterate as I said.